# Ethernet PHY RMII waveform without LAN Cable connected

Tags: voltage, ethernet, differential, high-speed, phy

Is the below waveform that I am getting in TX- line of Ethernet (PHY Used - [LAN8700](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/LAN8700#document-table)) correct? (Waveform obtained without connecting the LAN cable).

Using RMII mode in the PHY.  R801 & R803 (pin 1) are not present. R816 Not present (close to oscillator).

[image]

Zoomed picture:

[image]

Attached the schematic:

[image]

Please tell me why is the spike downward coming?

What might be the issue?

What could be the reason? HW/SW?

Comment: Termination resistors as mentioned in the schematic.

Comment: Yes, I see the *near-end* termination resistors. That doesn't mean the line is terminated - what's at the *probe* end?

Comment: These are likely link detect pulses which are monopolar and occur continuously. "Normal Link Pulse" -, NLP

Comment: Oh, Iet me check once

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you asking why there are pulses at all, or why the pulse edge has undershoot and overshoot?

Comment: Why it has undershoot and overshoot and one big spike overshoot

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue. What you’re observing seems to be typical when probing those circuits with a usual oscilloscope probe. The waveform is largely meaningless, because the signals are differential, and won’t look right without proper termination. Without the cable, there’s only half the termination needed, and the TX transformer has open secondary.

Comment: But there are proper terminations in the schematic? Is that enough to get proper signals?